# AWS Beanstalk - Customize app to create dynamodb tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my app (nodejs) using AWS beanstalk. I want to create DynamoDB tables during the deployment. I'm trying to use the customization feature of beanstalk, which means I'm trying to write a config file (YAML) under .exextensions. I want to create a table something like this:

TestTable with fields:

```
field 1 (hash key),
field 2 (range key),
field 3,
field 4, ..
```

.

When googling, I can find only examples of config files with a single field (e.g. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-environment-resources-dynamodb.html).

Looking for some examples of config files with tables containing multiple fields or a document containing the entire features/keywords of the YAML template of beanstalk.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamo DB is schemaless so you don't need to specify field3, field4 etc. You can specify key schema as shown on the page you linked. The specific example on the page only uses hash key for the dynamo DB table but you can also specify range key (field2) similar to how hash key is specified. Syntax of the config file needs to have RANGE key in addition to HASH key in KeySchema. It follows the cloudformation resource description syntax. See the following links for details:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-keyschema.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create a table on **each** deployment?
If the table is a resource that your app uses, I would go with `CloudFormation` to define your template (list of AWS resources that you need together, like - 3 EC2 machines, a load-balancer, an RDS server, a DynamoDB table and an ElasticBeanstalk app and environment). Then, your app will only get a reference to the table's name and use it (can be done using an environment variable).

If you haven't use `CloudFormation` before, you might find a slight learning-curve at the beginning, but at the end it's relatively simple. A template is a JSON file with declarations and after you upload your template, you can create many instances of it (for example - production and staging).
You can find a snippet of using `Elastic Beanstalk` in `CloudFormation` here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-elasticbeanstalk.html